# 10bit HDR To 10bit SDR Conversion With FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I know how to convert 10 bit HDR video to 8 bit SDR with FFmpeg, but i wonder if FFmpeg can do 10bit HDR to 10bit SDR conversion.

I always use this command line for my video conversions:

```
.\ffmpeg.exe -i input.mkv -vf zscale=t=linear:npl=100,format=gbrpf32le,
zscale=p=bt709,tonemap=tonemap=hable:desat=0,zscale=t=bt709:m=bt709:r=tv,
format=yuv420p -c:v libx265 -crf 10 -preset fast output.mkv
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

As you will observe using `ffprobe` on a HEVC 10-bit video file, the video format will most likely be `yuv420l10le`. Use `format=yuv420p10le` in your usual `ffmpeg` incantation for 10-bit output.

Answer (score -2):

As far as i know, it depends on x265 or x264 libraries...
You can activate 10bit output feature when configure each library...